# There exists $x\in B$ such that $x\notin A.$

Tags: logic

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets.  Statement: There exists $x\in B$ such that $x\notin A.$

> My Question: What is the negation of the above statement?

My Answer is: For every $x\in B,$ we have $x\in A,$  that is  $B\subset A.$ Is this correct?

Comment: Your definition of proper subset is incomplete. It doesn't say that $A$ is a subset of $B$ of any kind. Try your answer when $A$ is the set of even integers and $B$ is the set of multiples of $3$.

Comment: @EthanBolker: Thanks.    I assume the statement " there exists $x\in B$ such  that $x\notin A$"  What is the negation of this? Can you explain? Thanks

Comment: If you get told that your original title is not logically equivalent to the question that you asked in your description, don't change the title question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** because the OP changed the question. This is an answer to the one asked.

The assertion you want to negate is the definition of "proper subset":

> $A$ is a subset of $B$ and there is some $b \in B$ that's not in $A$.

The negation is

> Either $A$ is not a subset of $B$,  or (if it is a subset) it is all of $B$.

General remark for this kind of question. I think it's much easier to understand both question and answer with words instead of symbols where possible.

Answer (score 1):

Negation should be either $A = B$ or $A \setminus B \ne \emptyset$.

Comment: @Stefan  and Offlaw: Thanks. What is the negation  of statement : " There exists $x\in B$ such that $x\notin A$? Thanks I've edited the question.

Comment: Clearly $\lnot\exists x\in B.x\notin A ~~=~~ \forall x\in B.x\in A$

Answer (score 0):

*for the original question:*  No, $\lnot(A\subset B\land A\neq B)\iff (A\not\subset B\vee A=B)$

*for the updated question:* Yes, $\lnot\exists x\in B~(x\notin A) \iff \forall x\in B~(x\in A)$ and that means $B\subset A$

---

Note: A proper subset is defined as $A\subsetneq B~\iff~ \forall x\in A ~(x\in B)\land\exists x\in B~(x\notin A)$. That is: every element of $A$ is an element of $B$ *but* there are some elements of $B$ that are not elements of $A$.